# Проблемы с отображением кастомного JComponent

Tags: java, изображения, swing

Попытался создать свой класс `JImage`, наследующий `JComponent` и содержащий в себе картинку. Окно приложения запускается, но не видно самой картинки.

Главный класс:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window window = new Window();
    }
}
```

Класс с фреймом:

```java
public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window() {
        setSize(1000,500);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JImage img = new JImage();
        img.setLayout(null);
        img.setSize(100, 100);
        img.setLocation(100,100);
        img.setImage("img.png");
        img.setVisible(true);

        add(img);
    }
}
```

Класс с компонентом:

```java
public class JImage extends JComponent {
    Image img;

    public JImage () {}

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(getImage(), getLocation().x, getLocation().y, getSize().width, getSize().height, null);
    }

    void setImage(String filePath) {
        try {
            this.img = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Image getImage() {
        return this.img;
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему. Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Файл с картинкой существует, проверил в проводнике в корне проекта через `exists(new File(filePath))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно так рисовать изображение:

```
            g.drawImage(getImage(), 0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height, null);
```

здесь X и Y это координаты относительно самого компонента JImage.
Плюс

```
    setVisible(true);
```

из класса Window необходимо переместить в самый конец.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ про размер. 
Теперь изображение отрисовывается где надо, но только после изменения размера окна. Добавил repaint() в конец класса Window, но ведь другие JComponent (JButton например) показываются и без этого. Как моему такое же свойство дать?